# Where I can enter and present my programming skills?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, resume, software-industry, job-search

Is there any website in which I can record all my programming languages, frameworks, IDEs, to show it to possible customers/employers?

Everyone knows many job-application websites in which he can/have to put his skills in different programming languages on. In a normal job application I cannot put all the technologies I'm used to it because the list would be too huge.

This question seem basic, but still I'm having quite a hard time to describe what I want. So it already would be a help if someone could help me finding or describing something like that. Something which I thought I could use for that would be [Stackshare](http://stackshare.io), but maybe there is a website which is more fitting for this task.

Already thanks for the Answer of Lilienthal!

Comment: why not make your own website or blog? Then you can give yourself free rein.

Comment: Yes, I could make it. But it's not necessary. Because it's a specialized task which a website could do quite good. I'm wondering that there isn't any website yet known who can do that.

Comment: Perhaps it might depend on what you're aiming for in terms of who reads your stuff. I tend to find consultants through their personal sites and blogs, I wouldn't wade through a generic type dump site. But others might.

Comment: So, uh, have you never heard of LinkedIn?

Comment: LinkedIn is well known. But it is way more than only this task. And it's not well suited to show in a good way all the libraries and languages I can use. Did anyone looked at the Link of Stackshare I shown?

Comment: I didn't... no offence

Comment: @BerndErnst Just how many languages do you know? If you want to announce that information to the world, LinkedIn is perfectly suitable and the only universally known site. I can't think of any reason why you'd want to list libraries.

Comment: Post your programming projects on github and group them by language. This will showcase your actual abilities more than LinkedIn (which is just a list).

Comment: If the list is too huge to list then maybe the list is too huge.  If you were good at a huge list then jobs would find you.  I think you need to change your focus from a check list of stuff you know.

Comment: Having all the skills in the world will not help unless you know someone with influence.

Comment: Based on this question and the conversation that it sparked it sounds like your list is really too long to begin with. I understand the struggle of getting all your technical information without overfilling the allotted space. It's difficult, but necessary. You need to whittle it down to the job you're looking at or, in the case of just listing the information, maybe register your own site and group/document your skills there. There are plenty of examples of professional portfolio websites out there http://www.rleonardi.com/interactive-resume/ , http://www.barryclark.co/portfolio-examples/ etc

Comment: These days the best you can do is a heroku account linked to Github.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where I can enter and present my programming skills?

In your resume or on LinkedIn.

> Is there any website in which I can record all my programming languages, frameworks, IDEs, to show it possible customers/employers?

There are plenty, but none of them are particularly useful.

> In a normal job application I cannot put all the technologies I'm used to it because the list would be too huge.

Your application or resume is not supposed to exhaustively document every single concept, library, language or tool you've ever used. **It's a marketing document to highlight why your experience and skills are a good match for a particular position.** Being concise is critical. When you list skills or technologies you need to avoid being needlessly verbose but at the same time make sure that you specify those technologies that a hiring manager is looking for.

LinkedIn is of course a bit of a different animal as that's a general profile that isn't tailored to a particular job or company (while your resume should be). **It's important that you strike the right balance in deciding what skills to list there.** A list of hundreds will probably come across as dishonest or egomaniacal and will make it so no one can tell what your actual core focus is. LinkedIn has good reasons to limit you to 50 skills and even that is way too much for most profiles.

When (good) hiring managers are looking for profiles online, they aren't looking for a list of five dozen different keywords. They're looking for a few key skills or technologies and will quickly skim through the work history, titles, and skills you list to check if your profile could match their position. Listing every technology you've ever heard of is a sure way to convince someone that he's looking at a fake profile.